# How to Display SharePoint List data back into the Microsoft Form

Tags: list, flow, microsoft-forms

I made a Microsoft Form and stored data into SharePoint List with Flow. Now I want to send this data to my approver in the same Microsoft Form which I used to store data into the list so the remaining fields could be filled by the approving person.

I am stuck here and need step in Microsoft Flow Please can someone give me some hint.

Many Thanks,

Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing existing rows or otherwise getting access to already submitted data in another form is not a use case for Microsoft Forms. To edit existing submissions, either use an OOB SharePoint list, PowerApps, SPFx, or other 3rd party solution.

Comment: Thanks @Mike2500 for making it clear.